# Images are not loading into the home page from static

Tags: python, django, static

I dont know why image is not display on the home page. Please see my code. I am on windows running python3 and Django 2.1. Is there any setting need to be done in files somewhere in Django folders like any config file? Please guide

Settting File:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

URL file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import include, path
import jobs.views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('home', jobs.views.home, name='home'),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Model File

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Job(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

Home Page File

```
<html lang="en">
{% load static %}
  <head>
```

And where I want to show the image is end of a div

```
<img src="{% static '9.jpg' %}" height="200"></img>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Is there any relation between `Job` model and image from static directory?

Comment: refer to this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial06/

Comment: Yes it has connection ... image files are in static folder under the JOB Main folder under the ROOT folder of MySite

Comment: What image url is in the rendered html? What happens when you're trying to open this url manually (which http status/error code)? Where is this file located on drive (full path)? Please add this info to your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In settings.py you will need to add settings for MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL. That is what the ImageFile upload_to relates to. See the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/).

You can then for example reference the image in the home page template as follows:

```
<img src="{{ '/media/images/9.jpg' }}">
```

Comment: Glad it worked! Could you accept my answer as the correct one, please? :D

Comment: Done :) mate :)